# Apache Ignite data distribution issue

Tags: ignite

I am trying to load data into an Apache Ignite cluster using a Java thin client, but the data is not getting loaded evenly. I see that only one machine's memory is increased.

[image]

I followed this, added a custom affinity mapper. Version is 2.14.0
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.14.0/thin-clients/java-thin-client#partition-awareness

Update1: Adding code

```
ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration()
                .setAddresses("host1:10800","host2:10800",......)
                .setTimeout(10*60*1000) 
                .setPartitionAwarenessEnabled(true)
                .setPartitionAwarenessMapperFactory(new ClientPartitionAwarenessMapperFactory() {
                    @Override public ClientPartitionAwarenessMapper create(String cacheName, int partitions) {
                        final AffinityFunction aff = new MyAffinityFunction(partitions);

                        return new ClientPartitionAwarenessMapper() {
                            @Override
                            public int partition(Object key) {
                                return aff.partition(key);
                            }
                        };
                    }
                });

ignite = Ignition.startClient(cfg)

kmvpCache = ignite.cache(s"cacheName")

val kmvpBatch = new java.util.HashMap[java.lang.Long, Array[Byte]](params.batchSize)

for(....){
    for(....){
        kmvpBatch.put(<Key>, <value>)
    }
    kmvpCache.putAll(kmvpBatch)
    kmvpBatch.clear()
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Added code in the question

Comment: You have a custom affinity function, right? It could be the key, could you please share it?

Comment: Tried with `RendezvousAffinityFunction`, facing same issue.

Comment: Ok then, what are your keys? Do you have custom affinityKey? Just to be clear, you are getting the same results without having setPartitionAwarenessMapperFactory configured?

Comment: Facing the same issue, without setPartitionAwarenessMapperFactory also

Comment: Are you sure you are not touching only a narrow set of keys?

Comment: Yes @VladimirPligin